# Eloquent create not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel, so I face a problem in creating a post.

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('savepost', 'PostsController@savepost');
```

Here are my createpost.blade.php

```
@include('header')

  <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Create New Post</h3>

            <form action="savepost" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Post Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Enter New Title">
                </div>
                @if($errors->has('title'))
                    <p class="alert alert-danger"><strong>oopps! </strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }} </p>
                @endif
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Post Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <textarea name="description"></textarea>
                </div>

                @if($errors->has('description'))
                    <p class="alert alert-danger"><strong>oopps! </strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }} </p>
                @endif

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save Post">
                </div>

              </div>
            </form>

      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

@include('footer')
```

Here are my PostsController

```
class PostsController extends BaseController{

    public function createpost(){
        return View::make('createpost');
    }   


    public function savepost(){

        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Posts::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {


        Posts::create(array(
            'title'=>Input::get('title'),
            'description'=>Input::get('description')
        ));

        }
        else{
        return Redirect::route('createpost')->withErrors($validation);
        }

    }

}
```

Here are my Model:

```
class Posts extends Eloquent {

protected $guarded = array();
protected $fillable = array('name', 'description');


    protected $table = 'posts';

    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required|min:5',
        'description' => 'required'
    );
}
```

and here are my **posts** database

```
id    title   description   url   date
```

please help me

Comment: What is your problem? You havent told us anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posts table is missing the default laravel timestamps. Either turn them off in your model by doing:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Or add them to your posts table:

```
alter table posts add created_at datetime NOT NULL
alter table posts add updated_at datetime
```

Or create your own timestamps in your model.  I see you have a date column, so you can do something like:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'date';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both fillable and guarded.

> Of course, you should use either  $fillable or $guarded - not both.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment